# Do you score points for claiming a route in Ticket to Ride Pennsylvania?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, scoring

Do you score points for claiming a route in Ticket to Ride Pennsylvania as you do in all other variants of the Ticket to Ride game?

The rules aren't explicit and there is no scoring guide.

Answer (score 8):

In Ticket to Ride, the expansions rules feature the differences with the base game ones.

If the routes were not meant to be scored, it would be stated in the rules for that map.

On the Pennsylvania map, you score using the same points scheme as usual:

- 1 space   --> 1pt
- 2 spaces --> 2pts
- 3 spaces --> 4pts
- 4 spaces --> 7pts
- 5 spaces --> 10pts
- 6 spaces --> 15pts
- 7 spaces --> 18pts

This [backed by Alan R. Moon himself](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/20674407#20674407) on BGG

Answer (score 3):

The original USA map says under the rules for 'Claiming Routes':

> "When a player claims a route, he records the points he receives by
>   moving his Scoring Marker on the Scoring Track"

The Pennsylvania rules say as follows:

> "When a player claims a route, he may also take the top Stock Share
>   from any of the Railroads listed on the route he claims."

It also starts with:

> "This rules booklet describes the game play changes specific to the
>   Pennsylvania Map and assumes that you are familiar with the rules
>   first introduced in the original Ticket to Ride"

I take this to means that you do score points when claiming a route as this in the origional rules and taking a share is an additional optional action.  If the expansion rules says it assumes you are familiar with the original game and doesn't specifically say you don't score routes then that rule, along with all other basic rules, still apply.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to keep the convention of scoring for the tracks you place as per other TTR ride games. My beef is that I started with TTR Europe as my base game and there are no five place routes on that board, so it took quite a while to find out how much to score a five place route in the Pensylvania expansion. Indeed, because of the existence of five place routes in TTR Pensylvania we assumed initially that you didn't score routes as you placed them.